# Titanium does not compile Android app (Cannot read property 'sdks' of undefined)

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am trying to build my Android mobile app.

I have used the following command:

```
$ appc ti build -p android
```

However, it bizzarely gives me the following error:

```
Appcelerator Command-Line Interface, version 6.2.2
Copyright (c) 2014-2017, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

An uncaught exception was thrown!
Cannot read property 'sdks' of undefined
Cannot read property 'sdks' of undefined
```

What is going on and how do I fix this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is bug in Titanium cli: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-24751

You can fix this by installing windows sdk or patching the bug your self. Edit file `C:\ProgramData\Titanium\mobilesdk\win32\6.1.0.GA\windows\cli\commands\_build\config.wpSDK.js`

Add the fix from this pull request https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile_windows/pull/1006/files

Comment: Thanks! it was very helpful !